# To update a text box on onother textbox keypress MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I have 2 text boxes,On 1 text box I need to type the numbers based on the number it should get the data from a lookup table(where MyAge is the lookup table) based on the number that I enter in one text box

```
 @foreach (var pa in Model[i].MyAgeTable)
  {
    if (TextboxAge.trim() == pa.Trim())
    {
        ....
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this. For using jQuery you need to add the following in your head:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then the following code will do what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function (){

    $("#textBox1").keypress(updateTextBox2());


    function updateTextBox2() {
        // code to get update another textbox
    }
});
</script>
```

**[Documentation for .keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)**

There are different ways of writing the code to get the data from look up table. For instance you can make an ajax request to the server.

**[Documentation for jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**